# ActionMailer 2.3.8 is sending all of my mail in HTML format, regardless of what I do

Tags: ruby-on-rails, content-type, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm have a Rails 2.3.8 app, with a notifier in `app/models/hello_notifier.rb` that looks like this:

```
class HelloNotifier < ActionMailer::Base
    def hello_world
        @recipients = 'to@email.address'
        @from = 'from@email@address'
        @subject = 'Hello world'
    end
end
```

And a view in `app/views/hello_notifier/hello_world.erb` that looks like this:

```
Hello
World
```

Not when I run `HelloNotifier.deliver_hello_world`, it delivers the email, but it delivers it as a multipart email with plain and html variations.

I've tried adding `@content_type = 'text/plain'` to my notifier model as well as `content_type 'text/plain'`. I've also tried adding `ActionMailer::Base.default_content_type = 'text/plain'` to my actionmailer initializer. I've also tried renaming my view to `hello_world.text.plain.erb`. Nothing I try seems to help. It's always sending my email as a multipart html/text email.

Any ideas on how to force it to send as 'text/plain'?

Comment: did hello_world.text.erb not work? Or something like: mail(:to => user.email) do |format|
  format.text
end

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename your view to `hello_world.text.erb`

Comment: That's doesn't work at all. Then I get `ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template hello_notifier/hello_world.erb in view path app/views`. Just `hello_world.erb` and the full `hello_world.text.plain.erb` are both automatically found, but in both cases it renders as multipart with html.

Comment: I think that's the Rails 3 way. This is Rails 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 2.3.8 searches template with .erb extension with default content type text/plain.
Try to rename your file name to hello_world.erb

Comment: As stated in my post, I already tried that. That's the first thing I tried, in fact.

Comment: you never mentioned about .erb thats why i gave this solution.will update you if i got a solution.

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear, sorry. I wrote, "And a view in 'app/views/hello_notifier/hello_world.erb' that looks like this:" but didn't put it in a code block, so it would easy to pass over it. Updated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 2, you implicitly specify the content type of your email template by giving it one of the following file extensions:

- .text.plain.erb for plain text emails
- .text.html.erb for HTML emails

For example, "your_email_template.text.plain.erb" for plain text and "your_email_template.text.html.erb" for HTML.

See also: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned in my post, I already tried naming the file `hello_world.text.plain.erb` and it still sent it as multipart html + text.